# UIImagePickerController doesn't fit into the window when presented

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to develop a simple application which is going to work with the photos the user takes. By following https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html I am using a UIImagePickerController in order to take the snapshot. I have a basic application with a single, empty view controller and in the viewDidAppear method I do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Error" message: @"Can't use the camera!" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

    return;
}

UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

cameraUI.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController: cameraUI animated: YES completion:NULL];

}
```

The resulting view becomes something like:
[image: Image Picker]

As you can see the front-rear camera change button doesn't show completely and the UIImagePickerController does not fit into the screen. Should I additionally resize before presenting or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: you are running iphone target in **ipad**. Running it in **iphone** would solve your problem

Comment: No, I am running it on an actual iPad, but the app is intended for iPhones.

Comment: if app is made only for iphone then it will not work perfect in ipad

Comment: camera is not working on simulator so he must not be running it on simulator

Comment: just run it in iphone if it is designed for iphone only. it will work

Comment: Isn't there a way for me to reach the camera controls as a separate view and translate it a little downwards according to the screen size?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici: No worries it will be proper for iphone :)